# What is the difference between _A0 & _S0 log files when storing Google App Engine Standard logs in GCS

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

I have turned on the switch to send the logs of a GAE Standard app to a GCS bucket. I see there as expected a folder for each day. For every hour of every days I see a very big json file with the extension _S0.json. For some hours I also see a much smaller file with the extension _A0:.json. For instance:

01:00:00_01:59:59_S0.json  & 01:00:00_01:59:59_A0:4679580000.json

What is the difference, I am trying to post process the files and need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs exported to GCS are sharded, the `_A0` and `_S0` are simply identifiers of the logs shards.

From [Log entries in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#log_entries_in_google_cloud_storage) (emphasis mine):

> The leaf directories (`DD/`) contain multiple files, each of which
>   holds the exported log entries for a time period specified in the file
>   name. The files are *sharded* and their names end in a shard number,
>   **`Sn` or `An` (n=0, 1, 2, ...)**. For example, here are two files that might be stored within the directory
>   `my-gcs-bucket/syslog/2015/01/13/`:
>
> ```
> 08:00:00_08:59:59_S0.json
> 08:00:00_08:59:59_S1.json
> ```
>
> These two files together contain the syslog log entries for all
>   instances during the hour beginning 0800 UTC. To get all the log
>   entries, you must read all the shards for each time period—in this
>   case, file shards 0 and 1. The number of file shards written can
>   change for every time period depending on the volume of log entries.

I got to the above page via the last link in the below quoted section from [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#quotas_and_limits):

> Logs ingestion allotment
>
> Logging for App Engine apps is provided by [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/). By
>   default, logs are stored for an application free of charge for up to 7
>   days and 5GB. Logs older than the maximum retention time are deleted,
>   and attempts to store above the free ingestion limit of 5 gigabytes
>   will result in an error. You can update to the Premium Tier for
>   greater storage capacity and retention length. See [Stackdriver
>   pricing](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing) for more information on logging rates and limits. If you
>   want to retain your logs for longer than what Stackdriver allows, you
>   can [export logs to Google Cloud Storage, Google BigQuery, or Google
>   Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export).