# Google Cloud Storage Usage Pricing from byte_hours

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I recently setup the Google Cloud Storage Access Logs & Storage Data and the logs are getting logged but I could see 4 logs at the same time.

For example:

- usage_2017_02_14_07_00_00_00b564_v0
- usage_2017_02_14_07_00_00_01b564_v0
- usage_2017_02_14_07_00_00_02b564_v0
- usage_2017_02_14_07_00_00_03b564_v0

So there are 4 usage logs logged for every hour, what's the different between them.

I connected all the logs to big query to query the table - and all 4 of them have different values.

Also analysing on storage logs - I could see `storage_byte_hours` to 43423002260.

How to calculate the cost from `storage_byte_hours`?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for GCS to sometimes produce more than one logfiles for the same hour. From [Downloading logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#downloading) (emphasis mine):

> **Note:**
>
> - Any log processing of usage logs should take into account the possibility that they may be delivered later than 15 minutes after the
>     end of an hour.
> - Usually, hourly usage log object(s) contain records for all usage that occurred during that hour. Occasionally, an hourly usage log
>     object contains records for an earlier hour, but never for a later
>     hour.
> - **Cloud Storage may write multiple log objects for the same hour**.
> - Occasionally, a single record may appear twice in the usage logs. While we make our best effort to remove duplicate records, your log
>     processing should be able to remove them if it is critical to your log
>     analysis. You can use the **s_request_id** field to detect duplicates.

You calculate the bucket size from `storage_byte_hours`. From [Access and storage log format](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format):

> **Storage data fields:**
>
> ```
> Field                 Type        Description
> storage_byte_hours    integer     Average size in byte-hours over a 24 hour period of the bucket.
> ```
>
> To get the total size of the bucket, divide byte-hours by 24.

In your case 43423002260 byte-hours / 24 hours = 1809291760 bytes

You can use the bucket size to estimate the cost for the storage itself:

1809291760 bytes = 1809291760 / 2^^30 GB ~= 1.685 GB

Assuming Multi Regional Storage (per GB per Month ) $0.026 your storage cost be:

1.685 GB x $0.026 = $0.04381 / month ~= $0.00146033333333 / day (w/ 30 days month)

But a pile of other data (network, ops, etc) is needed to compute additional related costs, see [Google Cloud Storage Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the comments.. but multiple logs have the same size ( that's my concern) whether google is trying to write to multiple logs, if that is the case then it should vary for each hour. But for last 24 hours , I could see 4 logs for each hour, do no why??

Comment: So if 1809291760 bytes and I am using Multi Regional Storage (per GB per Month ) $0.026 - so how much it would for a day ??

Comment: I don't know exactly the reason, but I'd guess a possible one would be sharding from multiple instances (for scalability), as it's the case for logs exported from GAE. for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753876/what-is-the-difference-between-a0-s0-log-files-when-storing-google-app-engin